# C# ClickOnce ftp not working properly

Tags: c#, ftp, clickonce

after some research I made publish my files on ftp.

But when I download "setup.exe" file from web and trying run it, I getting error "Cannot Start Application"

I looked for same error but all answers was for others errors

Error summary was saying that my manifest may be not valid or file could not be opened, but then why other people can use ftp, create guides that its working.

```
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://www.marzuk.site11.com/webtest/ClickOnceWebTest.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from http://www.marzuk.site11.com/webtest/Application%20Files/ClickOnceWebTest_1_0_0_0/ClickOnceWebTest.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: br, br. Line 3, position 254.
```

**Some properties of publishing:**

1. Used software Visual studio 2013
2. Web hosting http://www.000webhost.com/
3. publishing folder location ftp://web.site11.com/public_html/webtest/
4. installation folder URL http://www.web.site11.com/webtest/
5. deployment web page default.htm

**So the main question is: What stopping setup from installation and what im doing wrong?**

**There is the full log of error:**

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO   Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)  Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34014   System.Deployment.dll       :
4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL     clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR   dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL   dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES     Deployment url          : http://www.web.site11.com/webtest/ClickOnceWebTest.application
                        Server      : Apache    Deployment Provider url     : http://www.web.site11.com/webtest/ClickOnceWebTest.application

IDENTITIES  Deployment Identity     : ClickOnceWebTest.application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=b3b9502bd69c8e4f, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY     * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY   Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.  * Activation of http://www.web.site11.com/webtest/ClickOnceWebTest.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:         + Exception reading manifest from http://www.web.site11.com/webtest/Application%20Files/ClickOnceWebTest_1_0_0_0/ClickOnceWebTest.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.      + Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: br, br. Line 3, position 254.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY     No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS   * [2014-06-27 16:09:22] : Activation of http://www.web.site11.com/webtest/ClickOnceWebTest.application has started.     * [2014-06-27 16:09:23] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.     * [2014-06-27 16:09:23] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS   Following errors were detected during this operation.   * [2014-06-27 16:09:23] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from http://www.web.site11.com/webtest/Application%20Files/ClickOnceWebTest_1_0_0_0/ClickOnceWebTest.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)             at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)          at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)          at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)             at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)        --- Inner Exception ---         System.Xml.XmlException
        - Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: br, br. Line 3, position 254.
        - Source: System.Xml
        - Stack trace:          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)           at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()           at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()          at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()          at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()          at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()          at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()          at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS     No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the manifest file is valid? Is the webserver configured to serve up .manifest files? Some configuration is required on the server to deploy clickonce applications. Try deploying it to a local web server first.

Comment: This is a borderline comment. I won't downvote, but this is really asking a clarification question and giving suggestions rather than an answer.

Comment: I downloaded manifest from web via filezilla, everything works fine. But about what configuration you are talking, never done any configuration.

Comment: why the obsession with downvoting people who are just trying to help?

Comment: Your web server needs to know what to do with the .manifest file. Under IIS you would add this as a mime type (from what I recall). Otherwise the server doesn't know how to send it back to the client, or even if it is allowed to send it back.

Comment: Oh, I will look further into this. Thank you.